# ¿Como puedo hacer una consulta a una BBDD acorde a lo que quiera?

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Saludos,

Estoy haciendo un programa y quiero que el mismo cuente con consultas de diferente tipo a la base de datos, pues me pidieron que hiciera las siguientes tipos de consulta:

- Buscar por cedula
- Buscar por nombres
- Buscar por enfermedades
- Buscar por rango de fechas (Entre dos fechas o una sola)

Tengo ya el modelo de como hacer la consulta pero solo por un solo tipo de parametro, en este caso por el nombre de la persona, pero quisiera saber como puedo hacer diferentes tipos de consulta y lo mas importante por rango de fecha.

Lo que tengo en la mente es poner un SELECT donde pida el metodo por el que quiero buscar y que ese parametro lo tome para realizar la busqueda pero no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo.

¿Alguien podria echarme un cable?

Les dejo el codigo que tengo.

**NOTA**: Tambien al hacer estas consultas necesito jalar datos de dos tablas distintas, una llamada **datosbasicos** y otra llamada **datosmedicos**

```html
<?php 

 function ejecuta_consulta($labusqueda){
 include("conexiond.php");

 $conexion= mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_usuario,$db_contra);

 if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

  echo "Fallo al conectar con la base de datos";
  exit();
 }

 mysqli_select_db($conexion,$db_nombre) or die ("No se encuentra la base de datos.");


 $consulta = "SELECT * FROM DATOSBASICOS WHERE NOM_PAC LIKE '%$labusqueda%'";

 $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

 while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultados, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

 echo $fila ['CED_PAC']. " ";
 echo $fila ['NOM_PAC']. " ";
 echo $fila ['APE_PAC']. " ";
 echo $fila ['TEL_PAC']. " ";
 echo $fila ['CEL_PAC']. " ";

 echo "<br> ";
 echo "<br> ";
 }

 mysqli_close($conexion);

 }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Sistema de historias médicas - Dr. Darling Davila</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <?php
  $mibusqueda=$_GET["buscar"];

  $mipag=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];

  if($mibusqueda!=NULL){
   ejecuta_consulta($mibusqueda);
  }else{
   echo ("<form action='". $mipag . "' method='GET'>
    <img src='imagenes/header.png'>
     <h2>Busqueda de paciente</h2>
     <div class='contenedor'>
     <input type='text' name='buscar' class='input-100 text-center inline-block col-md-6 btn-enviar espacio-arriba'></label>

     <input type='submit' name='enviando' value='Consulta' class='text-center inline-block col-md-12 espacio-arriba btn-enviar'>
    </div>
    </form>");
  }
 ?>


</body>
</html>
```

**ANEXO:**

Dejo fotos de mis dos tablas

[image: Tabla de datos basicos, necesito el Nombre, apellido, cedula edad y sexo.]

[image: Tabla de datos medicos, de acá necesito todos los campos.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que se suele usar para el tipo de consultas que quieres es [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html), uniendo las tablas mediante llave primaria/llave foránea.

Si tienes dos tablas:

- `datosbasicos (id_persona, nombre, cedula, fecha_nacimiento...)`
- `datosmedicos (id, id_persona, id_enfermedad, datomedico, fecha_consulta...)`

Y dichas tablas se relacionan por la columna `id_persona`

Puedes traer datos de ambas tablas mediante `JOIN`.

#### - Usando `LIKE`:

```
SELECT db.id_persona, db.nombre, dm.datomedico, dm.fecha_consulta 
FROM datosbasicos db
INNER JOIN datosmedicos dm ON db.id_persona=dm.id_persona 
WHERE db.nombre LIKE '%Juan%';
```

Hay que tener en cuenta algunas cosas:

- `db` y `dm` son usados como ALIAS de las tablas `datosbasicos` y `datosmedicos`
- Si quieres que el LIKE te funcione tanto para `juan` como para `Juan` la columna `nombre` de la tabla debe ser declarada `case insensitive (ci)`

#### - Por cédula:

```
SELECT db.id_persona, db.nombre, dm.datomedico, dm.fecha_consulta 
FROM datosbasicos db
INNER JOIN datosmedicos dm ON db.id_persona=dm.id_persona 
WHERE db.cedula = 'numero-cedula';
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que si `cedula` es del tipo `INT` el criterio se escribe sin comillas simples: `WHERE db.cedula = 10783643`

#### - Entre dos fechas:

Existen varias posibilidades, la más común es usar [`BETWEEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) :

```
SELECT db.id_persona, db.nombre, dm.datomedico, dm.fecha_consulta 
FROM datosbasicos db
INNER JOIN datosmedicos dm ON db.id_persona=dm.id_persona 
WHERE dm.fecha_consulta BETWEEN '2017-07-31' AND '2017-08-31';
```

#### - Por enfermedad:

```
SELECT db.id_persona, db.nombre, dm.datomedico, dm.fecha_consulta, e.enfermedad 
FROM datosbasicos db
INNER JOIN datosmedicos dm ON db.id_persona=dm.id_persona 
INNER JOIN enfermedades e  ON dm.id_enfermedad=e.id_enfermedad
WHERE dm.id_enfermedad = 4;
```

Aquí se supone que tienes también una tabla aparte llamada `enfermedades`, de ese modo evitas innecesariamente tener el nombre de la enfermedad en `datosmedicos` y relacionas por una llave (`id_enfermedad`). Como puedes apreciar, esta última consulta te trae datos de tres tablas diferentes usando `JOIN`.

---

> **NOTAS IMPORTANTES:**
>
> - Sugiero que leas también sobre Inyección SQL. Para el tipo de
>     aplicación que estás creando vas a necesitar dar un mayor nivel de
>     seguridad a tu código.
> - Si usas el engine `InnoDB` al crear las tablas debes establecer las restricciones (constraints) para que las columnas relacionadas en
>     las tablas se manejen de forma adecuada y no queden datos huérfanos.
>     Por ejemplo, que si una persona es borrada de la tabla `datosbasicos`
>     no queden los datos de esa persona huérfanos en la tabla
>     `datosmedicos`.
> - Deberás indicar igualmente cuáles son las llaves primarias/foráneas de cada tabla.
> - Para que las consultas sean optimizadas y no haya datos repetidos deberás establecer los índices de cada tabla adecuadamente.

Comment: Wow muchas gracias por esta respuesta amigo, pondre en practica esto inmediatamente para ver si me funciona y si tengo algun problema escribire por acá inmediatamente, tomare todas tus recomendaciones en cuenta.

Comment: Padre Cedano, hice lo que usted me indico pero el resultado no me esta arrojando nada , ¿Podría ayudarme? 

`$consulta = "SELECT datosbasicos.ced_pac,datosbasicos.nom_pac,datosbasicos.ape_pac,datosbasicos.sex_pac,datosmedicos.cod_consulta,datosmedicos.alt_pac,datosmedicos.peso_pac,datosmedicos.fecha,datosmedicos.tipo_consulta,datosmedicos.sintomas,datosmedicos.observ,datosmedicos.his_pac,datosmedicos.medi_pac,datosmedicos.operado,datosmedicos.alergias FROM datosbasicos INNER JOIN datosmedicos ON datosbasicos.ced_pac=datosmedicos.ced_pac WHERE COD_CONSULTA LIKE '%labusqueda%'";`

Comment: @PabloPernia hay que tener en cuenta que: 1) Los nombres de columnas podrían ser case sensitive... ¿la columna `COD_CONSULTA` se llama así, en mayúsculas, en la tabla? 2) Es mejor poner en cada nombre de columna a qué tabla pertenece, también a las columnas del WHERE, o sea, `WHERE nombretabla.cod_consulta` 3) No es obligatorio que la consulta retorne datos, no retornará datos si no hay error de sintaxis y no se cumplen los criterios de búsqueda. Para depurar puedes correr la consulta en PHPMyAdmin y ver si regresa datos o da mensaje de error de sintaxis.

Comment: Efectivamente tenia razón Padre, depure en PHPMyAdmin y tenia varios errores, mas sin embargo no me funciono con el WHERE, le quite el where y me funcionó así: 

`"SELECT datosbasicos.CED_PAC,datosbasicos.NOM_PAC,datosbasicos.APE_PAC,datosbasicos.SEX_PAC,datosmedicos.COD_CONSULTA,datosmedicos.ALT_PAC,datosmedicos.PESO_PAC,datosmedicos.FECHA,datosmedicos.TIPO_CONSULTA,datosmedicos.SINTOMAS,datosmedicos.OBSERV,datosmedicos.HIS_PAC,datosmedicos.MEDI_PAC,datosmedicos.OPERADO,datosmedicos.ALERGIAS FROM datosbasicos INNER JOIN datosmedicos ON datosbasicos.CED_PAC=datosmedicos.CED_PAC";`

Comment: Con el WHERE sería así, ¿Sabrá aqui donde esta el error? cambie de **DM** a **DB**  **datosbasicos** como a **datosmedicos** 
`SELECT datosbasicos.CED_PAC,datosbasicos.NOM_PAC,datosbasicos.APE_PACac,datosbasicos.SEX_PAC,datosmedicos.COD_CONSULTA,datosmedicos.ALT_PAC,datosmedicoscos.PESO_PAC,datosmedicos.FECHA,datosmedicos.TIPO_CONSULTA,datosmedicos.SINTOMAS,datosmedicos.OBSERV,datosmedicos.HIS_PAC,datosmedicos.MEDI_PAC,datosmedicos.OPERADO,datosmedicos.ALERGIAS FROM datosbasicos INNER JOIN datosmedicos ON datosbasicos.CED_PAC=datosmedicos.CED_PAC WHERE COD_CONSULTA LIKE '%labusqueda%'";`

Comment: @PabloPernia la consulta no parece tener ningún error de sintaxis, salvo que si la columna `COD_CONSULTA`  existiese en ambas tablas y aunque no exista (como te dije antes), es mejor que le pongas el nombre de la tabla, es decir:  `WHERE datosmedicos.COD_CONSULTA LIKE...`. ¿Pudiste ejecutarla en PhpMyAdmin? ¿Revisaste que no hay ningún nombre de columna mal escrito? Si todo eso está verificado y no arroja datos significa que no existen datos con el criterio de búsqueda o que no cumple la condición del JOIN. Puedes probar también un `LEFT JOIN datosmedicos ON ...` en vez del `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Padre Cedano, logre solucionarlo cambiando esta parte `WHERE datosbasicos.CED_PAC LIKE '%$labusqueda%'";` le puse el simbolo **$** Y me funciono sin problemas.

Ahora tengo una duda, si quisiera realizar las busqueda de diferentes maneras, ¿Como podría hacerlo? es decir, usted me dio los ejemplos, pensaba en hacer un **input select** donde tuviese las opciones, luego obtener esa opcion (No se si mediante un GET) y que dependiendo de eso ejecute la busqueda mediante un **IF**? Pero no se si se puede.

Comment: Entiendo, @PabloPernia. Te funciona porque `$labusqueda` representa en tu código PHP la variable que contiene los criterios de búsqueda. No obstante, no es una forma segura de consultar a la base de datos, por lo que te comenté de la Inyección SQL. En cuanto a tus otras dudas, Stackoverflow funciona por preguntas. Es decir, no podemos resolver todos los aspectos de un problema en una sola pregunta. Recomiendo que des esta primera duda por solucionada marcando la respuesta que te haya ayudado a resolver este problema y que plantees una nueva pregunta con esa nueva interrogante.

Comment: Muchas gracias Padre Cedeno, soy nuevo en SO, hare lo que usted me dijo y consultaré por otro post, de verdad mil gracias por su enseñaza, es valiosa para mi.

Answer (score 0):

**Buen día**

Para tu *SELECT* debes tener dos condiciones básicas:

1. Usuario con permisos (por lo menos de SELECT desde luego) a las BD en las cuales necesitas hacer la(s) búsqueda(s).
2. En cada *SELECT* ya sea en el FROM y/o JOIN, UNION...etc colocar el nombre de la BD seguido "." nombre de tablla; a continuación ejemplo (con las ilustraciones que proporcionaste):

> /* Voy a colocar "tabla[1|2]" debido a que en las ilustraciones no
>   logre identificar el nombre respectivo de cada una */

```
SELECT CED_PAC FROM DATOSBASICOS.tabla1    
UNION ALL    
SELECT CED_PAC FROM DATOSMEDICOS.tabla2
```

Cada *SELECT* anterior debera estar acompañado de su respectivo *WHERE* como corresponda.

De la forma anterior consultas en ambas tablas de distinta BD sin realizar dos conexiones; ten en cuenta que para el UNION realizado ambos resultados deben ser idénticos en cantidad de columnas y tipo de dato; consideración que deberas tener al momento de aplicar.

Desde luego; que lo anterior es para obtener en un solo query los datos "necesarios"; tambien por si necesitas otros datos completamente distinto (ya sea que sea el mismo numero de columnas pero distinto tipos de datos), dos query cada uno con su `SELECT [CAMPOS] FROM BasedeDatos.Tabla [...]`; sin necesidad (obligada) de tener que realizar dos conexiones a la BD.

Comment: Muchas gracias Roberto, creo entender lo que dices, pero me quedo una duda, el SELECT los datos de ambas tablas tienen que ser de mismo **TIPO** o tienen que ser **IGUALES** para que me arroje los resultados, pues por ejemplo en la tabla datos basicos necesito consultar diferente nombres de campos algunos string otros INT.

En datosmedicos lo mismo, algunos INT y otros string.


¿SI le das click a la imagen no se te abre? a mi si, por eso las coloque.

Muchas gracias Roberto.